# how to notify method that something is done

Tags: c#, .net

My constructor besides other things call another method DoWork

```
public MyTask(TaskAction action)
{
   DoWork(action);
}
```

DoWork method goes to another method Calc(2)

```
private void Calc (int 2){
   ... calc and save result into file         
}
```

How can I alert MyTask that Calc is done and let MyTask to continue further.

P.S. I could read hdd every few secs in order to see whether file with result is save and based on that continue further, but I assume that there is better way.

Comment: I don't think putting all that behavior in the constructor is a good idea in the first place (you could be surprised if `DoWork()` or `Calc()` become `virtual` later, for instance). In addition, from the code you posted it looks like both `DoWork()` and `Calc()` are synchronous, so letting `MyTask()` "continue further" is not an option. Could you elaborate a little more on your architecture?

Comment: @FredericHamidi your comment point me in a new direction. I will change my question later. Thanks

Comment: Have a look at ContinueWith - it will allow you to specify task(s) that run after a task has completed.

Comment: If that `DoWork` calls `Calc` synchronously, then that DoWork will continue as soon as Calc has finished. When DoWork has finished, then your constructor will continue.

Answer (score 0):

`BackgroundWorker` class allows you to easily manage your async work.

```
        BackgroundWorker _worker = new BackgroundWorker();

        public Cnt()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _worker.DoWork += WorkerOnDoWork;
            _worker.RunWorkerCompleted += WorkerOnRunWorkerCompleted;
            //start your work
            _worker.RunWorkerAsync();    
        }

        private void WorkerOnRunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Worker completed event
        }

        private void WorkerOnDoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            //Do   
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this.The latest recommended is using tasks

```
Task taskA = new Task(() => { Console.WriteLine("Task A started"); });
taskA.ContinueWith((ss) => { Console.WriteLine("Task A finished"); });
taskA.Start();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372288(v=vs.110).aspx
This way you can block the current thread if you want.

Another way is the BackGroundWorker Class

Also, you can use a custom callback like this

```
using System;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
   class Program
   {
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
        DoWorkA(DoWorkFinished);
        Console.Read();
     }

    private static void DoWorkA(Action whatToDoWhenFinished)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Doing something");
        whatToDoWhenFinished();
    }

    private static void DoWorkFinished()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Doing something Else");
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Did you just copy and past that verbatim from MSDN?

Comment: I think you will need to change a bit more than just that.